# ListFile processor, force processor to list full directory everytime

Tags: apache-nifi

My use case.

`Some processing somewhere else add files to some dir (_use_it) -> call my flow using REST -> Now I want my process to read all files from mentioned directory (_use_it).`

I want to read all files everytime from this directory, not just changed/added files. I can't start/stop process. This flow has to run as a background process.

I think, I am looking for ListFile processor to run once, then stop, and then when It runs again, it forgets previous state. "some twisted logic" :)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***1. Using GetFile Processor:***

You can use **GetFile** processor instead of **ListFile + FetchFile processors** and **GetFile** processor `doesn't store the state`.

- GetFile processor Gets all the files in the directory every time.
- **Keep Source File** property If **true**, the file is `not deleted` after it
  has been copied to the Content Repository; this causes the file to be
  picked up continually and is useful for testing purposes. If not
  keeping original NiFi will need write permissions on the directory it
  is pulling from otherwise it will ignore the file.

(or)

***2. Using ListFile Processor:***

Making use of [NiFi RestAPI](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) we can clear the state of list file processor and then processor will list out all files in the directory every time.

Clear state of the processor:

```
POST 
/processors/{id}/state/clear-requests
```

Before you are starting the Listing all files in the directory flow

1. Use Rest Api to stop the ListFile processor
2. Clear the state of ListFile processor
3. Start the ListFile processor.

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/64771/unable-to-updateexecute-processor-though-nifi-rest.html) and [this](http://apache-nifi-developer-list.39713.n7.nabble.com/Reg-starting-and-Stopping-processor-td7930.html) links to STOP the processor via RestApi

Comment: both sounds promising, is thr a easy way to put processor_id in attribute? I will have to pass it from ListFile processor down to REST  (which is last processor in the flow).

Comment: I don't think there is a easy way unless we add each processor_id using `UpdateAttribute` Processor and **adding processor_id attribute**. (or) By using **NiFi RestAPI processor groups (/process-groups/{id}/processors)** to list out all the processors in the processor group.